# How to change a row background color according to the value of one cell?

Tags: python, pandas, row

I have been trying to change the background color of a row based on where the key is present in my lists.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


item_added = ["UUID1", "UUID22"]
item_removed = ["UUID2", "UUID89"]
item_changed = ["UUID3", "UUID100"]


def highlight_cells_condition(val):
    if val in item_added:
        color = "green"
    elif val in item_removed:
        color = "red"
    elif val in item_changed:
        color = "yellow"
    else:
        color = ""

    return ["background-color: {}".format(color)]


arr = np.array(
    [
        ("UUID3", "TYPE1", 0, "AA", "time1", "Items"),
        ("UUID2", "TYPE2", 0, "BB", "time2", "Items"),
        ("UUID1", "TYPE1", 1, "CC", "time3", "Vaalves"),
    ]
)
header = ["UUID", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]
df = pd.DataFrame(num, columns=header)

df.style.applymap(highlight_cells_condition)  
html = style.to_html()
with open("output.html","w+") as fh:
    fh.write(html)
```

I can understand that `applymap` highlights only the cells for those values are matching in highlight_cells_condition.

Is there a way where I could extend to change the complete row instead of only the cell?

Please see that I am a beginner to pandas and any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to define a new function:

```py
def highlight_row_condition(row):
    if row["UUID"] in item_added:
        color = "green"
    elif row["UUID"] in item_removed:
        color = "red"
    elif row["UUID"] in item_changed:
        color = "yellow"
    else:
        color = ""
    return [f"background-color: {color}" for _ in row]
```

Then running the following expression in a Jupyter notebook cell:

```py
df.style.apply(highlight_cells_condition, axis=1)
```

Outputs:

[image]